# Why the area under the probability density function curve is probability

Tags: statistics

Why is the area under the probability density function(PDF) curve gives probability?

Comment: That's pretty much the definition of a probability density function to me.  Maybe, could you explain how you think about pdfs?

Answer (score 2):

The cumulative distribution function (CDF) is *defined* as a probability, that the random variable $X$ involved is lower or equal than a certain value, $x$,  $F_X(x) = P(X\le x)$. This can be extended to $P(x_1\le X \le x_2) = F_X(x_2) - F_X(x_1)$. The probability density function, $f_X(x)$, when it exists, is *defined* as the derivative of the CDF, 
$$ \frac {dF_X(x)}{dx}=f_X(x)$$. Then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(x)dx = F_X(x) = P(X\le x) $$

and

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f_X(x)dx = F_X(x_2) - F_X(x_1) = P(x_1\le X \le x_2) $$

So this integral measures probability, and it can be viewed also as measuring "the area under the PDF curve".